# google search tab key for jump from one link to another

Tags: windows-7

When I search in google in my ubuntu box, just after page result loaded i can press tab key for jump from link to link, but I can't do the same thing in windows 7 and 8 (it goes from one control to another instead of links). Do you know why? It worked time ago.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds more like a browser issue than an OS issue

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Im using Google chrome

Comment: I've reinstalled chrome without succes.